# namespace and vector not found with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

I am getting an `error: 'vector' does not name a type` with [established source code](https://github.com/teju85/CorrDim). I crated a project with the NetBeans IDE and MinGW installed via Installation Manager mingw-get version 0.6.2-beta-20131004-1. The compiler command line is: `gcc    -c -g -Isrc -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/basics.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/basics.o src/basics.cpp`

The offending code is:

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> listMaps() {
    ....
}
```

I added

```
#include <vector>
```

which fails, so I guess I need to install additional modules with mingw-get. How can I identify what is missing from the installation?

Comment: Is `<string>` included?

Comment: Also, where exactly did you add `#include <vector>`, in the header or in the source file?

Comment: Use `g++` to compile C++ code

Comment: Exactly, just wanted to point that out.. you beat me to it @M.M

Comment: Start a fresh project and compile "hello world" with `#include <vector>` added, that will tel you whether it is an issue with your installation or not

Comment: Thanks, gcc seems to be wrong. I have to figure out why NetBeans uses it in a C++ project which I created.

Comment: Fresh project same as offending code removed in original project, with #include <vector> works fine. Added #include<string> as suggested.Still: g++    -c -g -Isrc -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/basics.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/basics.o src/basics.cpp
src/basics.cpp:30:1: error: 'vector' does not name a type

Comment: What package is vector part of in a mingw32 installation, where should it be found? What version should it be? We should be able to verify using more analysis.

Comment: It works now, My mingw32 installation was incomplete. Thanks to both @M.M and iksemyonov for pointing out the other issues. If you post an answer then I will select it.